# Android AUTO : Is there a way to stream video on Android Auto ? Like camera feed or conferencing calls?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-auto, android-automotive

I am looking into ways of **streaming video from an Android app to the infotainment system through Android Auto** connection.
I know you can only use the available templates for building the UI, like list, grid , message or navigation templates, and the template components are limited to buttons, headers and rows and so on, but there is nothing close to image or video view in those template components.

So if there are any workarounds to stream video on Android Auto please let me know. Also I am trying to do this on a custom android device where I have access to all the firmware / AOSP code so I can change stuff in there.